# How to hide my presence in the Friends app?

Tags: friends-app

I am usually on Facebook via the web page but with chat turned off.
However, every time I turn on to the Ubuntu Friends app it makes my FB chat presence online as a consequence of which I am accosted by ghosts from the past :-(
To boot, it also turns my chat presence online on the FB web page, Empathy etc...

Effing annoying. Is this another "feature" needs to disabled somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it not directly related to Ubuntu and it's kind of workaround but I hope it helps. Create group of friends let's say "nochat". In group "nochat" put fake account or some friend you'll never talk. Then go into advanced settings of chat and put that group of friends in field: "Turn on chat for all friends except...". In that way it wouldn't matter if you are online or not. When you want to use chat simpy delete that group from advanced settings. :)